# Complex data type in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, complex-numbers

Why can't we enter the imaginary part in complex data type in formats other than decimal number (for example octal/binary/hex)? In real part we can use any form (hexadecimal/octal)

Ex.1:

```
x = 0B1111 + 20J     #  => valid
```

Ex. 2:

```
x = 0B1111 + 0b111J  #  => Syntax Error
```

Comment: There is no "real part". There is only a regular number added to a complex one.

Comment: Hi @MisterMiyagi Thanks for your reply.Can you please elaborate more what it mean by only regular number added. And also x = 0B1111 + 20J in this what is the regular number & real part.

Answer (score 3):

Because in Python, complex numbers are represented as a pair of floating point numbers and have the same restrictions on their range:

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#imaginary-literals

```
imagnumber ::=  (floatnumber | digitpart) ("j" | "J")
```

There is no binary literal support for `float`s therefore it raises a syntax error.

When you write `0b11+2j`, the real part (`0b11`) is implicitly converted to a `float`.